# RegexValidator in Django Models not validating email correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I'm making a django form with an email field and using a RegexValidator and want a specific format of of the email but it seems to be not validating the field correctly

```
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r"^[2][2][a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}@[nith.ac.in]*",
                message=
                "Only freshers with college email addresses are authorised.")
        ],
    )
```

When I am entering the email ending with @nith.ac.in or @nith.acin both are getting accepted while @nith.acin should not get accepted... any sols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[nith.ac.in]` does *not* parse literal text, it parses any character in te group, meaning it can end with a sequence of `n`s, `i`s, `ni`s, etc.

Your regex should look like:

```
email = models.EmailField(
    unique=True,
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'^[2][2][a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}@nith[.]ac[.]in$',
            message='Only freshers with college email addresses are authorised.',
        )
    ],
)
```